# Magento: Load a particular product collection

Tags: magento, collections

I just want to do a simple product collection by extending Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List. Is something not ok here and i can't figure out what:

community/block

```
class folder_subfolder_Block_Mage_Catalog_Product_List extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List
{
    public function getLoadedProductCollection($limit)
    {
       $collection = parent::_getProductCollection();

       $collection      
                        ->clear()
                        ->setPageSize($limit)
                        ->addOrder('entity_id')
                        ->joinField(
                                'qty',
                                'cataloginventory/stock_item',
                                'qty',
                                'product_id=entity_id',
                                '{{table}}.stock_id=1',
                                'left'
                            )
                        ->addAttributeToFilter('qty', array('eq' => 0))
                        ->load();

        return  $collection;
    }

}
```

Also have an empty class Helper and etc config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Folder_Rkproductlists>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Folder_Rkproductlists>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <helpers>
            <rkproductlists>
                <class>Folder_Subfolder_Helper_Data</class>
            </rkproductlists>
        </helpers>
        <blocks>
             <rkproductlists> 
                <class>Folder_Subfolder_Block_Mage_Catalog_Product_List</class>
             </rkproductlists>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

tried toload this collection by:

```
<reference name="content">
<block type="subfolder/mage_catalog_product_list"  template="catalog/product/templatename.phtml">
        <action method="setCategoryId"><category_id>54</category_id></action>
        <action method="setLimit"><value>3</value></action>
    </block>
</reference>
```

Comment: What kind of error do you get? What did you expect to happen, what actually happened?

Comment: No error. i've included that reference in CMS Page and not even enters in the template file...

Comment: when you try to override any block you have to follow magento way.in your config,xml rewrite for that block.check [my question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16786439/re-write-toolbar-for-grid-on-front-side-magento)  will perhaps solve your question.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for my problem:

```
class Folder_Subfolder_Block_Mage_Catalog_Product_List extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List
{

    protected function _getProductCollection()
    {
       $collection = parent::_getProductCollection();

       $collection      
        ->clear()
        ->setPageSize( $this->getLimit() )
        ->addAttributeToFilter('qty', array('eq' => 0))
        ->load();

        return  $collection;
    }
}
```

and config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Redkiwi_Rkproductlists>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Redkiwi_Rkproductlists>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <helpers>
            <rkproductlists>
                <class>Redkiwi_Rkproductlists_Helper</class>
            </rkproductlists>
        </helpers>
        <blocks>
            <rkproductlists> 
                <class>Redkiwi_Rkproductlists_Block</class>
            </rkproductlists>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```